# Choosing the OS when dualbooting

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-8

I've just finished installing Ubuntu, and now have Ubuntu in one partition and Windows 8 in another. I was under the impression that when my computer starts, I would be able to choose from a menu which one to run. However, what happens instead is that Ubuntu runs automatically if I don't press anything, or if I press escape I get a menu which includes only ubuntu and something called memtest - no Windows.

How am I supposed to run Windows?

Please avoid too much technical language and give me step by step instructions wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the command `sudo update-grub`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reinstall grub loader in order to display both Ubuntu and Windows at startup.

You can do it with **boot-repair** software, it will install grub on your system.

Open terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and give following command to install and run **boot-repair** software.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (sudo boot-repair &)

boot-repair
```

Then click the "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, reboot your system and check that you can access both Ubuntu and Windows or not.

For more information visit [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).